# Is the comma (separating two independent clauses) necessary here?

Tags: commas

> Our head office is in London{,} and we have offices across England, Scotland & Wales.

Is this comma necessary? I searched in google and saw many cases where they omit it in this particular place. For instance:

> Our head office is in London and we have a regional branch in Dubai.

So, should the comma be there or not?

Comment: It's a matter of personal choice rather than correctness. As the  second sentence is shorter, there is less need for a comma marking a pause.

Comment: @kate-bunting But isn't it two independent clauses?

Comment: @KateBunting Most writing advice says that a comma is required before the coordinating conjunction, for example, https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/independent_and_dependent_clauses/index.html It’s incorrect even though most people will overlook it if the meaning of the sentence can be inferred from the context.

Comment: @ColleenV OK, I stand corrected.

Comment: @KateBunting whatever the authorities say I agree with you that a comma seems hardly necessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Our head office is in London and we have a regional branch in Dubai.

This compound sentence has an error known as fused sentence.

https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sentelmt.aspx#comma%20splices

> Error #2: The Fused Sentence

> Writers make this error by joining two independent clauses into a compound sentence without using any punctuation between them.

> No punctuation between the two independent clauses causes them to "fuse" into an INCORRECT compound sentence.

We can repair that by adding a comma before the coordinating conjunction, replacing the coordinating conjunction with a semi colon, or using a conjunctive adverb with a semi colon and comma.

> Our head office is in London[,] and we have a regional branch in Dubai.

> Our head office is in London[;] we have a regional branch in Dubai.

> Our head office is in London[; also,] we have a regional branch in Dubai.